# Child webpages help

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Using C#, ASP.Net

In my webpage i have the link for the another web page, if i click the link that should display a another page inside the main page like child page.

Another webpage should display like a popup window in my webpage. And also size of the another webpage should be small. How to do this.

Need Help.

Comment: Wait...Let me read it again!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying one web page within another look at using [frames (or an inline frame - iFrame)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp)

The second part of your question I think is asking to be able to display the link in a separate window. To do this, use the target="blank" attribute in the anchor tag. to set the size of the child window you will need to use javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPopup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=190,width=520,top=200,left=300,resizable');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
</script>
```

So just call the showPopup method from your anchor click event

```
<a href="http://www.yoururl.com" onclick="showPopup('http://www.yoururl.com');">link text</a>
```

Ideally you would move the javascript so that it is no longer inline, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you need a [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

For the second part you might need a [modal popup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) or it's [jQuery equivalent](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

However, I don't understand what you mean with

> And also size of the another webpage should be small. How to do this.

Comment: +1 thought about the master page but was confused with this question.

Answer (score 0):

> Another webpage should display like a
>   popup window in my webpage. And also
>   size of the another webpage should be
>   small. How to do this.

Did you mean a [jQuery Modal Window](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial)?